# Creating a HttpModule that routes traffic to another server

Tags: asp.net, httpwebrequest, httprequest, httpresponse, httpwebresponse

I ran into a rather tricky problem at one of my clients. They have a simple router which can only forward a single port to a single machine. However, they have several applications on several servers requiring port 80.

So, I was thinking I could write a `HttpModule` that receives traffic and creates a `HttpWebRequest` to another internal server. When the `HttpWebResponse` comes back, the `HttpModule` writes the content to the `HttpResponse`.

Has this  been done before? And does it make sense?

Comment: unfortunately, no budget for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Microsoft Application Request Routing Version 2.5 for IIS 7

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=a58d3bfc-e17e-4749-93f4-474081358b44

Comment: Thank you very much! I will look into this first thing on Monday and report back.